# Good text to image generator with edit functions, live preview?

Tags: image, text

My customer wants an interesting application. The basic functionality is quote generator. the user writes the best quote he knows, the end result is a nice image of quote. he would like that user can:
- change background color
- change font color
- change font size
- preview function, so the user can see what he made - this can probably be html preview with jquery...

Does anybody knows similar script or see something like this made before? Any tips where i should start? I will defenitly post the code when im done :)

Thank you :)